# Open source Miro alternative for home server

Tags: cloud-service, server, raspberry-pi

I built a home server using raspberry pi in order to host my own cloud services instead of relying on google & other paid alternatives. Currently I am running casaOS. I'd like to host my own Miro-like whiteboard app as my job requires a lot of collaboration and Miro turned out to be very helpful.

Can anyone tell about any alternatives that would allow me to share access to it and that I can host on my server?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that [Collaboard](https://www.collaboard.app/self-hosting-on-premises-aws-azure) can be hosted on premise, i.e. on a local server but I have no experience with it.

Note that it seems not free or open source software.